Is $Spa(k[[t]],k)$ equal to $Spa(k[[t]],k[[t]])$
Consider $X=Spa(k[[ T]],k)$ where $k[[t]]$ is equipped with $t-$adic topology. This spectrum consists of valuations $\nu$ such that $\nu(k)\leq 1$. Since $\nu$ has to be continuous we get that $\nu(T)<1$. Now consider $Y=Spa(k[[T]],k[T])$. There is a natural map $Y\to X$. Is it a homeomorphism? Intuitively, every valuation $\nu\in X$ satisfies both $\nu(k)\leq 1$ and $\nu(T)<1$ so it automatically belongs to $Y$.
